# How can i keep an active GUI on a windows server to automate processes

Tags: windows, server, automation, rdp

I am trying to automate an installation and execution of programs on my Windows Server (2019) but fail to do so when the RDP is minimized or closed. As the execution of the program will take place over 30+ days i cannot keep the RDP window maximized.

I have Changed the libraries and methods of installing from creating automated clicks to finding the window and invoking the buttons, but all fail as soon as the rdp window is not open anymore.

I have also tried starting the rdp through another windows server as i have read that the seconds rdp should still be active, but this has also not shown any signs of success.

I need the Windows server to keep running the GUI actively at 1080p (preferably) or at any set resolution.

Comment: locking the desktop should keep the session active, otherwise your scenario is very special!

Comment: Locking the desktop does not keep the GUI session alive though. I have managed to do this by running a command from cmd:
 ```FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=3 usebackq" %%X in (`query session %USERNAME%`) DO tscon %%X /dest:console```